# Cannot Add Class Attribute to @Html.DropDownListFor in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, attributes, html-select

I have a method for populating a DropDownList in my project and I want to show some records in Colour in this DropDownList. In order to make some items in colour, I wanted to add Class or some another style properties to the certain items before returning these items from Controller to View. But, unfortunately although the attribute seems to be added to the certain items, the colour or the styling properties for these items cannot be observed on the @Html.DropDownListFor in the View and when inspecting the DropDownList after populating,  there is not such a kind of attribute neither Select not Option tags. Could you have a look at the code below and inform me how can I solve the problem without using JQuery or another technology? Thanks in advance.

**Controller:**

```
private void PopulateMeetingsDropDownList(object selectedMeetings = null)
{
    var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
        .Join(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID,
            (m, c) => new
            {
                CityID = c.CityID,
                CityName = c.CityName,
                MeetingDate = m.MeetingStartDate
            }
        )
        .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(
            i => new
            {
                CityID = i.CityID,
                DisplayValue = string.Format(
                    "{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})",
                    i.CityName, i.MeetingDate),
                    Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow
            }
        ).ToList();

    //Here is the code for check and add Styling Attributes
    var selectItems = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
    foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
    {
        var item = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem
        {
            Text = record.DisplayValue,
            Value = record.CityID.ToString()                  
        };
        if (record.Expired)
        {
            item.Attributes.Add("class", "disabled");
            //item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:#4cff00");
        }
        selectItems.Add(item);
    }  
    ViewData["MeetingId"] = new SelectList(selectItems, "Value", "Text", selectedMeetings);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeetingId, ViewData["MeetingId"] as SelectList,"Select", 
        new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId"})
```

As it might be seen on **[this](http://imageupload.co.uk/files/ga5yqin1dhf3xrvtikdz.png)** screenshot, the "class" attribute and its value "disabled" returns from Controller, but they are not seems on the Dropdown attributes on the View. 
**Note:** When adding this attribute to an Option or Select tag on Firebug it works without any problem. So, there is no problem for the css class or this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write [your own HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) for that, as the Html.DropDownListFor only processes the Selected, Text and Value properties of a list item.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But although I have tried to create a custom Dropdownlist and Class attribute, I have not managed. Could you give me an example suitable for MVC4 please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: m1kael: Sorry, but although I have tried to use many different ways, the problem has not been solved yet. I created a custom html helper also. Could you have a look at this page and help me please? Thanks in advance... Set Class Attribute for certain records of Dropdownlist in MVC4